# Web browsers making request to server twice

Tags: node.js, browser, server

I wrote a simple nodejs code to make request to a server and noticed that on web browser the request is made twice but once when I use CURL.

```
const http = require('http');

// The server should respind to all request with a string "Hello World"
let count = 0;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end(`${++count} Hello World \n`);
})

// Start the server and have it listen on port 3000

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('The server is is listening on port 3000'));
```

[image: on browser]

[image: on curl]

Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is a preflight request to `OPTIONS`.  You could look at the network tab in the Chrome console to see.  You probably only want to respond to the `GET` request.